# iOS - error while archiving OCR demo

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

Im trying to use [OCR demo project](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo) and I modified the code, compiled and run the code which does all the above fine, when but I try to archive it, Im getting an error

```
error: strip /Users/mac1/xfer/Ananth/Projects/OCRSample/Resources/nolanbrown-Tesseract-iPhone-Demo-6338e61/OCRDemo/Classes/tesseract-3.01/vs2008/lib/liblept.lib: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip received signal 11
```

I didn't ever faced this error before and so I surfed but didn't find any relative solutions to it. Can someone help me guess the cause for this error and rectify it? 
Im using xcode version 4.3.2 and Mac OS, version 10.7.4

Any timely help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to strip the binary?

Comment: I didnt strip, I was just trying to archive I dont know what does it mean. Can you please explain me?

Comment: Ananth, did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Altaveron, yes I did,. Sorry for not posting the answer. I've answered it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this one needs `UIViewController` class having `.mm` extension to execute this library. Initially, I created a normal `UIViewController` class which would've a file with `.m` as extension on which I got the above error. 
I couldn't create a `.mm` file either. So I used the `OCRDemoViewController.mm` as my `UIViewController` and did modifications in it which solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "!< arch >" on the beggining of the file with "\x00< arch >".